# Why it is printing g two times?

Tags: c

Can someone explain me this program please

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(void)
{
   printf("g");
}

int main()
{
    void(*message)(void);

    print();    // i have doubt here it g

    message = print; // now here why it is printin g again

    (*message)();

    return 0;
}
```

this program brings a `void` function at first which is just `printf` now when we go to `main` function the first line indicates the pointer message which is void it didn't get the cose afterwards

Comment: _Side note:_ Using a function pointer, you can invoke it [as you've done] with: `(*message)();` But, you can also use a slightly cleaner/simpler version: `message();` The compiler will infer that this means `(*message)();`

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of "[How do function pointers in C work?](/q/840501/90527)"

Answer (score 8):

You're calling `print` twice: once directly:

```
print();
```

And once through a function pointer:

```
message = print; 
(*message)();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it is printing "g" twice is because you are calling the function print() both before and after you assign the function pointer.

You are essentially doing this:

```
print(); // this calls the function print()

message = print; // this assigns the function pointer message to point to the function print()

(*message)(); // this calls whatever function the function pointer message is pointing to, which happens to be print()
```